# Is there any way to see progress towards achievements in Civ 5?

Tags: civilization-5, achievements

Is there a way to see how much more I have to do to achieve the various achievements? For example, Merchant King is Trade 100 resources over any number of playthroughs... I'd love to know how close I am.

Comment: You may wish to reconsider which answer you have accepted, [@CowWarrior's](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/263202/104515) answer is the most updated solution, and is the only one which works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question dates a little but in my opinion is still very relevant being in the top 10 daily on Steam Stats. GunnarJ has the right idea but now you need to re-enable the debug log:

1. Open the `config.ini` file (located in **Documents\My Games\Sid Meier's Civilization 5**) and change  `LoggingEnabled = 0` to `LoggingEnabled = 1`.
2. Re-start Civ-V and you should now have the `achievements_debug.log` file available in **Documents\My Games\Sid Meier's Civilization 5\Logs**

Here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CT9I0NpFaxE) if you prefer.

There's also a tool you can use to analyze the debug file: [civalog.com](https://civalog.com/) if you don't want to go through the pain of analyzing `achievements_debug.log` yourself.

Comment: As of 2023-01-21 the flag can be enabled on MacOS generating the achievements_debug.log file.

Comment: Full path is `Library/Application Support/Sid Meier's Civilization 5/Logs/achievements_debug.log`

Answer (score 8):

> This file has been removed as of the [January patch](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1714352). As such, as of now there is no method to check achievement progress.

<strike>Actually, there is a way to view achievement progress, although it is a little troublesome to find and interpret. In the folder Documents\My Games\Sid Meier's Civilization 5\Logs is a file called "achievements_debug.log". If you open it, and scroll down you can find the values of different steamstat variables that can be interpreted into your progress for the achievements. For example:

`[49597.863] DBG: Steam Stat: ESTEAMSTAT_ROADS = 85`

This line says that I have built 85 roads, and the achievement that had to do with roads is to build 1000, so I would have to build 915 more to get the achievements. The file should contain everything you need to know about your progress on the achievements. If you need any help, feel free to ask.</strike>

Comment: Weird, I don't seem to have this file. Do I have to do something special to make it show up?

Comment: I can't think of any reason that it wouldn't be there, but, considering that it ends with "debug", it may be generated only under specific parameters.

Comment: It looks like this stopped working after the last patch. A shame as that would be handy. 

Not the greatest source, but here it is anyway: 
http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=1714352

Answer (score 7):

Unless the game itself is programmed to display your progress towards the steam achievements (Team Fortress 2, Left 4 Dead, Alien Swarm, Trine, etc.) there is no way to know how close you are, barring meticulous tracking on your own.