# Civ 5 Wonder tracking

Tags: civilization-5, achievements, steam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to see progress towards achievements in Civ 5?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11322/is-there-any-way-to-see-progress-towards-achievements-in-civ-5)

Is there somewhere accessible in the game to see what wonders you have built previously...?
I guess the same applies to what units you have built previously.

This is in reference to the Steam achievements for having built all the Wonders and all the units (2 separate achievements).

Comment: @Oak I think this is a different question. The one you linked to is to do with achievements, which are awarded across however many games you play, whereas this one is relative to the game you are currently in.

Comment: It would definitely be useful to keep track of what city has what wonder, or if they have not been discovered, just a place you can see that the wonder already exists.

Comment: @danixd but didn't Albort explicitly wrote that is asking in reference to the Steam achievement? That means he is asking about global history, not per-game.

Comment: @Oak You are completely correct, my bad. I agree with you then, it seems like the same question!