# Civilization 5: The Wonder Years

Tags: civilization-5, achievements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any way to see progress towards achievements in Civ 5?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11322/is-there-any-way-to-see-progress-towards-achievements-in-civ-5)

> **The Wonder Years** – Build all the Wonders, across any number of playthroughs.

Is there any way to determine which wonders still need to be built to earn this achievement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  They used to have a debug file which you could access to track progress towards achievements, but it is gone now, so you'd have to track it yourself.